# Numbering Duplicated names in comma-separated row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am stuck in a query and have no idea what to do. I need to number every duplicate name in a comma-separated row

[image: Sql Query Result]

For example in attached picture, Row 7th has Midazolam two times. So in this case first name should be Midazolam(1) and second should be Midazolam(2) and so on. Is this possible using a SQL query somehow?

Here is a query to generate dummy database and data:

```
USE [master]
GO
/****** Object:  Database [DummyDataBase]    Script Date: 10/5/2015 12:42:30 PM ******/
CREATE DATABASE [DummyDataBase]
 CONTAINMENT = NONE
 ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = N'DummyDataBase', FILENAME = N'c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\DummyDataBase.mdf' , SIZE = 30720KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 1024KB )
 LOG ON 
( NAME = N'DummyDataBase_log', FILENAME = N'c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\DummyDataBase_log.ldf' , SIZE = 16576KB , MAXSIZE = 2048GB , FILEGROWTH = 10%)
GO
ALTER DATABASE [DummyDataBase] SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 110
GO
IF (1 = FULLTEXTSERVICEPROPERTY('IsFullTextInstalled'))
begin
EXEC [DummyDataBase].[dbo].[sp_fulltext_database] @action = 'enable'
end
GO
ALTER DATABASE [DummyDataBase] SET ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [DummyDataBase] SET ANSI_NULLS OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [DummyDataBase] SET ANSI_PADDING OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [DummyDataBase] SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [DummyDataBase] SET ARITHABORT OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [DummyDataBase] SET AUTO_CLOSE OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [DummyDataBase] SET AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS ON 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [DummyDataBase] SET AUTO_SHRINK OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [DummyDataBase] SET AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS ON 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [DummyDataBase] SET CURSOR_CLOSE_ON_COMMIT OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [DummyDataBase] SET CURSOR_DEFAULT  GLOBAL 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [DummyDataBase] SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [DummyDataBase] SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [DummyDataBase] SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [DummyDataBase] SET RECURSIVE_TRIGGERS OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [DummyDataBase] SET  DISABLE_BROKER 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [DummyDataBase] SET AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS_ASYNC OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [DummyDataBase] SET DATE_CORRELATION_OPTIMIZATION OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [DummyDataBase] SET TRUSTWORTHY OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [DummyDataBase] SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [DummyDataBase] SET PARAMETERIZATION SIMPLE 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [DummyDataBase] SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [DummyDataBase] SET HONOR_BROKER_PRIORITY OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [DummyDataBase] SET RECOVERY SIMPLE 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [DummyDataBase] SET  MULTI_USER 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [DummyDataBase] SET PAGE_VERIFY CHECKSUM  
GO
ALTER DATABASE [DummyDataBase] SET DB_CHAINING OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [DummyDataBase] SET FILESTREAM( NON_TRANSACTED_ACCESS = OFF ) 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [DummyDataBase] SET TARGET_RECOVERY_TIME = 0 SECONDS 
GO
USE [DummyDataBase]
GO

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[TestTable]    Script Date: 10/5/2015 12:42:31 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestTable](

    [DrugName] [text] NULL,
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
INSERT [dbo].[TestTable] ([DrugName]) VALUES ('Midazolam, Ranitidine, Midazolam, Propofol, Cephazolin, Lignocaine, Propofol, Propofol, Fentanyl, Fentanyl, Oxygen, Isoflurane, Oxygen, Isoflurane, Oxygen, Isoflurane, Oxygen, Isoflurane, Oxygen, Nitrous Ox, Oxygen, Nitrous Ox, Isoflurane, Oxygen, Nitrous Ox, Plasmalyte, Plasmalyte, Plasmalyte, Plasmalyte, Isoflurane, Oxygen, Isoflurane')
INSERT [dbo].[TestTable] ([DrugName]) VALUES ('Midazolam, Ranitidine, Midazolam, Propofol, Cephazolin, Lignocaine, Propofol, Propofol, Fentanyl, Fentanyl, Oxygen, Isoflurane, Oxygen, Isoflurane, Oxygen, Isoflurane, Oxygen, Isoflurane, Oxygen, Nitrous Ox, Oxygen, Nitrous Ox, Isoflurane, Oxygen, Nitrous Ox, Plasmalyte, Plasmalyte, Plasmalyte, Plasmalyte, Isoflurane, Oxygen, Isoflurane')

USE [master]
GO
ALTER DATABASE [DummyDataBase] SET  READ_WRITE 
GO
```

Comment: Any chance you can just paste in some sample data rather than the screenshot? I can't read it, and more importantly I can't copy/paste to fiddle with it.  Also, what database are you using?

Comment: Why are you storing CSV in column.

Comment: Normalize your data instead of this mess.

Comment: @HartCO Query is added. I am using Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: @Fireblade This is representing my one item set, I need to apply machine Learning techniques on this.

Comment: @dnoeth I am not supposed to normalize this data because need to apply Machine learning techniques on this item set

Comment: Machine learning has nothing in particular to do with poorly-structured data.

Comment: @JohnBollinger This is one item set. It's not poorly structured it is supposed to be like this.

Comment: It is a one-item set whose item happens to be a *list* whose members have independent significance (else your question would not arise in the first place).  Your database does not satisfy even 1st normal form.  That is what I mean by "poorly structured".  Better structure would make the problem much more tractable.

Comment: @John Bollinger members are dependent on each other as I want to find pattern using Association rule mining.In Association rule mining Items are in one column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately, storing a list of values in a single field will create headaches.  The solution, even if you don't want to store the values in a normalized fashion, is to split the listed values into separate rows.  I use `XML` functionality to split the string into separate rows, then apply a `ROW_NUMBER()` and a `COUNT()` to change the names as desired.  Finally using `XML` functionality again to rebuild the lists.  If you want the order of the names in the lists to be preserved you'll have to add numbering for use in the `ORDER BY`:

```
;WITH  cte AS (SELECT RTRIM(LTRIM(Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)'))) AS Txt,ID    
               FROM  (SELECT CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(DrugName, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS DATA
                            ,ID
                      FROM #test
                     ) AS A CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a))
      ,cte2 AS (SELECT *,CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID,Txt ORDER BY ID,Txt)AS VARCHAR(50)) AS RN
                        ,COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY ID,Txt) AS Dup_CT
                FROM cte
                )
SELECT DISTINCT ID,STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' +   CASE WHEN Dup_CT > 1 THEN Txt+'('+RN+')' ELSE Txt END
                                    FROM cte2 a
                                    WHERE a.ID = b.ID
                                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') 
                                    ,1,1,'')

FROM  cte2 b
```

Note:  I'm assuming you have an `ID` field along with each string, if not you'll need to add one for this solution, so it can differentiate between rows after separation.

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/aade9/1/0)

Comment: Thank you so much .One last question is it required to order data alphabetically?.Isn't it possibe to get result in the same order?

Comment: @SafiMustafa To order in the original order, you'll need to add in an ID or numbering field for each row output from the first cte, then use that field in the `ORDER BY` of the final query.